# Finding the oldest person in Prolog

Tags: prolog

Based on some facts, I have to find the oldest person using Prolog. For example:

```
age(john, 10).
age(mary, 15).
age(rose, 75).
age(jack, 49).
age(carl, 17).
age(lucy, 66).
```

Console output should be:

```
?- oldest(rose).
True.

?- oldest(X).
X = rose.
```

My code is as follows, but it's not working:

```
oldest(P) :- age(P, X) , age(_, Y) , X >= Y.
```

I can't find the error, but I guess it's something related to backtrack. Could someone help me, please? I'm new to Prolog.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the correct one should be

```
oldest(P) :- age(P, X) , \+ (age(_, Y) , Y > X).
```

that yields rose, of course...

`(\+)/1` read as [not](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=%5C%2b/1)(Goal), and means 'fail if there are no solutions to Goal'.

*edit* in SWI-Prolog, library([aggregate](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=aggregate)) can do this, and much more...

```
oldest(P) :- aggregate(max(A,Pers), age(Pers,A), max(_,P)).
```

Comment: It works, thanks! But what's the difference between this definition and mine? Why does this work and mine doesn't?

Comment: your code find the first person that has *almost* one younger

Comment: @renatov if you read your `oldest` predicate literally, it says, "`P` is the oldest **if** `X` is the age of `P` *and* there is anyone whose age is `Y`, *and* `Y` less than or equal to `X`". So it will succeed if it finds just one person who is younger than `P`. It doesn't establish the constraint that *all* of the others must be younger.

Comment: @mbratch I see it clear now. You're right, it's actually asking if there is some P who is older than someone, not necessarily older than every single person in DB. Now I understand, thank you very much for your time!

Answer (score 1):

Your `oldest/1` definition is not valid (and CapelliC's answer shows why and how to fix it).

Here is another way find an oldest person:

```
oldest(X) :-
  findall((Age, Name), age(Name, Age), List),
  sort(List, SList),
  reverse(SList, [(_, X) | _]).
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked. But isn't there a more parsimonious way of doing that? Oh, and why my definition of oldest/1 isn't valid?