# Finding the oldest person in Prolog Query

Tags: prolog

I have a question to this: [Finding the oldest person in Prolog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19619476/finding-the-oldest-person-in-prolog)

Data:

```
age(john, 10).
age(mary, 15).
age(rose, 75).
age(jack, 49).
age(carl, 17).
age(lucy, 66).
```

So this query will return the oldest person:

```
oldest(P) :- age(P, X), \+ ( age(_, Y), Y > X ).
```

I am new to Prolog and I am having a hard time to understand this query, especially the `\+` part.

What I understand: to get the oldest person we take all persons with an age of X, without those persons with an age of Y bigger than X. But this would return the youngest person. I am confused :D

Can you help on reading this query?

Comment: It reads: P is a person (who's age is X) such that there is no other person for which his/her age is higher than P's age.

Comment: @gusbro I understand, post it as an answer please.

Comment: Even more interesting: add `age(tony,75).` And ask the question again! You will not get the oldest person but the oldest persons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It reads:

**P** is a person (who's age is **X**) such that there is no other person for which his/her age is higher than **P**'s age.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way to read the *predicate*

```
% For all person P, P is the oldest person if 
oldest(P) :-
    % exist X such that the age of P is X, and
    age(P, X),
    % do not exist Y such that Y is the age of some person and Y > X.
    \+ (age(_, Y) , Y > X).
```